# Prove that the graph $y=x^{3/5}$ has a vertical tangent at the origin.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My first attempt was to just differentiate and get $y'=\frac{3}{5x^{2/5}}$ and the at the origin, the gradient is $\infty$, but I'm not sure if this is sufficient enough.

Then I differentiated using the definition of the derivative as a limit to try and make it more formal but I'm still not sure if that suffices.

Any ideas on how to 'prove' this properly?

Answer (score 5):

I would go about finding the inverse of the function and showing that the tangent line at zero has a slope of 0.

$$y=f(x)=x^{3/5}$$
$$f^{-1}(x)=x^{5/3}$$
$$\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}=\frac{5}{3}x^{2/3}$$
$${\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}}_{|x=0}=0$$

Comment: That seems like a good approach. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could find dy/dx, then use that to find when dy/dx is infinity OR doesn't exist, in other words, when the bottom line of the fraction = 0.

I.e, 5x^(2/5)=0,
            x=0,
    Therefore, dy/dx doesn't exist when x=0, therefore, point at x=0 has a vertical tangent.
    When x=0, y=0^(3/5)=0,
    So, the point with the vertical tangent is (0,0) which is the origin

Comment: Welcome to Math@SE! Try using LaTeX formatting next time if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Your idea for a solution is completely fine.

To be formal, the derivative of $f(x)=x^\frac{3}{5}$ is $f'(x)=\frac{3}{5x^{2/5}}$.

Hence $f'(0)\neq\infty$, but rather $f'(0)\ \nexists$.

To show the tangent is vertical you only want to show that $lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=\infty$ or $lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=-\infty$ as you were thinking and you will be done.